# Special permission set for the task created in state machine workflow is not working

Tags: workflow, state-machine

I have created state machine workflow to the list in farm solution, that assign task to the user for approval. But the task can be viewed and edited by any other user, so i searched to set the permissions for task and found the link
 http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2008/01/workflow-tasks-which-can-only-be.html 
 but the permissions are not set. Pls help me

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to List setting
2) Click  Advanced Settings
3) change "Read access" to "Only their own"
4) then change "Edit access" to to "Only their own"

so it fix your problem ?

also create column "assigned to" and click "Modify this view" then go to Filter where you find "Show items only when the following is true:" and set "assigned to is equal to [Me]".